# Remote login to windows pc/laptop via SMS using window service C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, authentication

I have a requirement at hand which is to logon the user to his/her pc when the user send the sms command to a modem connected to the pc/laptop. Right now i have not written any window service code and i am still exploring and planning on how to go about doing it but i have a winform application that can receive and process sms from user as well as send sms back to the user. So i forsee that i will be able to use the same code to code the window service to receive sms command from user and process it. But my question is how do i login the user to the computer with the given username and password in the sms.

I have found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but from what i read is that this feature can only  provide a token handle to impersonate the specified user or, in most cases, to create a process that runs in the context of the specified user. But what i want to do is to login the user to a computer. For instance the computer is in log off mode with the modem connected to it and once the login sms command is received the pc should login the user. Can someone guide me or provide me on some suggestion on how to go about doing this in windows 7 ? Thank in advance for any help or suggestion provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the similiar question somewhere else and got the answer. Here is the [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/9ac20f65-ab89-4f4a-9210-0a4793b797cd).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308403) on how the logon in Windows is designed.

Comment: Thanks for having look at this thread and providing some suggestion. But it did not help much to resolve my problem. Anyway thanks for the effort.